# Override Html.DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-controls, html-helper

I have a definition table in Mysql.
It so easy, For. example

```
GroupId Name
1       Colors
2       Size

DefinitionId GroupId Name
1            1       Black
2            1       Green
3            2       S
4            2       M
```

I use DropdownListFor. I want to create custom control like DropDownList.
ForExample:

Html.CustomDropDownList("sizeId", 2) <--- 2 is Group of size.

How can I create control like this.

At the end is return to have something like this.

```
<select Id="sizeId" name="sizeId">
  <option value="3">M</option>
  <option value="4">S</option>
</selec>
```

Comment: Not clear what your asking. What are you wanting the output to be?

Comment: Its easy. Like DropdownListFor. It will be return select option elements

Comment: What options? What html do your expect this method to generate?

Comment: If you want to display only 2 elements in the dropdown, filter the list in controller and bring only 2 elements in the list.

Comment: Probably missing I told. I updated the question.

Comment: No @JibinBalachandran, for example:  "2" my color groupId. It wil be return like "...from mysql where groupId=2"

Comment: Then just generate a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in your controller based on the filtered result your want and return it to the view and use `@Html.DropDownListFor()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually It is so easy.

```
//This overload is extension method accepts name, list and htmlAttributes as parameters.
    public static MvcHtmlString DefinitionFor(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, int GroupId, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        // ref to db

        var db = (Service.Interfaces.ISet<Definition>)
        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(Interfaces.ISet<Definition>));

        //Creating a select element using TagBuilder class which will create a dropdown.
        TagBuilder dropdown = new TagBuilder("select");
        //Setting the name and id attribute with name parameter passed to this method.
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("Key", name);
        dropdown.Attributes.Add("Id", name);

        //Created StringBuilder object to store option data fetched oen by one from list.
        StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();
        //Get Item(s)
        var items = db.Get(new Definition() { Group = new Group() { Id = GroupId } }).List;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            //Each option represents a value in dropdown. For each element in the list, option element is created and appended to the stringBuilder object.
            options = options.Append("<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.Key + "</option>");
        }
        //assigned all the options to the dropdown using innerHTML property.
        dropdown.InnerHtml = options.ToString();
        //Assigning the attributes passed as a htmlAttributes object.
        dropdown.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        //Returning the entire select or dropdown control in HTMLString format.
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(dropdown.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Then, I can call like this.

```
<div>
    @Html.DefinitionFor("colorId", 2, new { @class = "form-control" });
</div>
```

Happy coding!